# How to convert simple struct in go with json structure

Tags: go

I am new to GO and I have one query with struct. I am want to convert below strut

```
type Dog struct {
  ID      int
  Name    string
  Breed   string
  BornAt  time.Time
}
```

to

```
type JSONDog struct {
  ID     int    `json:"id"`
  Name   string `json:"name"`
  Breed  string `json:"breed"`
  BornAt int64  `json:"born_at"`
}
```

is there anyway to automatically create it as if there are 100 of struct like that it will take long time manually.

Comment: This is usually an IDE feature, e.g. in VS Code you can execute "Add Tags to Struct Fields" from the command palette (to get closer to your output, you would also have to configure `go.addTags` in settings, e.g. set its `options` to an empty string). There are also command-line tools to add tags

Comment: json library in go does not require to have these tags for each struct field if name in json and name of field match. This notation should be used if they do not match, but not automation can help you in this case.

Comment: I got both you points thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the JSON you can take your JSON and something like this online convert to get the struct:

https://transform.tools/json-to-go

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```

will be

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    UserID    int    `json:"userId"`
    ID        int    `json:"id"`
    Title     string `json:"title"`
    Completed bool   `json:"completed"`
}
```